# Erl_eterm doc and erl_interface.h information conflict?

Tags: c++, c, erlang, erl-interface

I do not understand the following between [erl_eterm](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_eterm.html) and [erl_interface.h](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/erl_interface/include/erl_interface.h)

In [erl_eterm](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_eterm.html) the following are described as:

```
ETERM *ERL_PID_NODE(t)
ETERM *ERL_PID_NODE_UTF8(t)
ETERM *ERL_PORT_NODE(t)
ETERM *ERL_PORT_NODE_UTF8(t)
```

Where as in [erl_interface.h](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/erl_interface/include/erl_interface.h) they are defined as

```
#define ERL_PID_NODE(x) erl_atom_ptr_latin1((Erl_Atom_data*) &(x)->uval.pidval.node)
#define ERL_PID_NODE_UTF8(x) erl_atom_ptr_utf8((Erl_Atom_data*) &(x)->uval.pidval.node)
#define ERL_PORT_NODE(x) erl_atom_ptr_latin1((Erl_Atom_data*) &(x)->uval.portval.node)
#define ERL_PORT_NODE_UTF8(x) erl_atom_ptr_utf8((Erl_Atom_data*) &(x)->uval.portval.node)
#define ERL_REF_NODE(x) erl_atom_ptr_latin1((Erl_Atom_data*) &(x)->uval.refval.node)
```

If ERL_ATOM_PTR/ERL_ATOM_PTR_UTF8 needs to be used together with ERL_ATOM_SIZE/ERL_ATOM_SIZE_UTF8 to construct a NULL terminated c-string (char*), the same should be true for ERL_*_NODE* macros as they are all defined similarly. And none of them return ETERM* as defined in doc.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is `ETERM` defined as?

Comment: [ETERM](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/erl_interface/include/erl_interface.h#L287) and [erl_atom_ptr_*](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/erl_interface/include/erl_interface.h#L197)